# Angular 2 cannot find module after npm install

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

I have an Angular 2 app, and I'm trying to install `angular2-autosize` component in it (https://github.com/stevepapa/angular2-autosize) as per the instructions in the README of the package. I run below:

```
npm install angular2-autosize --save
```

which completes successfully. I can see a `angular2-autosize` folder in the 'node_modules' directory.
Also, a dependency is added to my package.json for
`"angular2-autosize": "^1.0.1"`

Now, I go to my `app.module.ts` file, and add this:

```
import { Autosize } from 'angular2-autosize';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ..
    Autosize
```

And try to build, with `ng build`, which fails saying,

> Cannot find module 'angular2-autosize'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed

`import { Autosize } from 'angular2-autosize';`

in the `app.module.ts` file,
to,

`import { Autosize } from 'angular2-autosize/angular2-autosize';`

and it worked :)

Comment: what to do with "corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json" error?

Answer (score 0):

There is many problem with this npm package (actual version is 1.0.1).
In fact this package has no index.ts file, so you need to reference the file it conatins. It is for that you need to specifies the file in your import :

```
import { Autosize } from 'angular2-autosize/angular2-autosize';
```

Secondly, the package does not include a bundle javascript file, so when you compile your application, the compiler will want to include the Autosize directive in your own javacsript file. You should see something like this in your javscript file (I know it is ugly) :

```
System.register("../../node_modules/angular2-autosize/src/autosize.directive", ["@angular/core"], function (exports_67, context_67) {
...
});
```

But may be that in your tsconfig.json file you exlcude the node_modules directory, so in this case you can get errors like :

> corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json

In this case, you can try to remove the node_modules directory from the exclude entry of your tsconfig.json file.